# How to translate field names using vee-validate and vue-i18n

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate, vue-i18n

Documentation on i18n integration with vee-validate is incomplete, in my opinion. I still can't figure out on how to translate field names, if i use i18n with vee-validate.

Here's my main.js:

```
import ruValidation from 'vee-validate/dist/locale/ru'
import enValidation from 'vee-validate/dist/locale/en'

Vue.use(VeeValidate, {
  i18nRootKey: 'validations',
  i18n,
  dictionary: {
    en: enValidation,
    ru: ruValidation
  },
  errorBagName: 'vErrors',
  events: ''
})
```

But the question is - how can i translate attributes? I've tried:

```
import attributesRU from './locales/veevalidate/ru/attributes'

  dictionary: {
    en: enValidation,
    ru: { message: ruValidation, attributes: attributesRU }
  },
```

Contents of attributes.js:

```
export const attributes = {
  mail: 'Эл.почта'
}
```

Input:

```
<input type="text" name="mail" v-validate="'required|email'">
```

But no success, even messages are not being translated, if i add:

```
ru: { message: ruValidation, attributes: attributesRU }
```

instead of:

```
ru: ruValidation
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Do you want to customize the dictionary for showing custom messages?

Comment: @PulkitAggarwal, look at my `<input>` it has a name and validation rule - required. If validation is failed, it shows "field mail is required", and after i've added a russian locale, as i mentioned in the question, it translated it to russian "поле mail обязательно". The message itself get's translated, but not the field name, in my case it's "mail", i want to translate that "mail" to a different languages. I hope i explained clearly.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55045730/841830

Comment: https://medium.com/js-dojo/connect-i18n-and-vee-validate-nuxt-js-i18n-and-vee-validate-works-greate-together-d086edd4ca22
guess I have already explained in my article.

Answer (score 3):

Its difficult to answer your question without seeing more of your code. I have setup a working codesandbox for your input element [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/j24ym66qm5). This successfully translates the error message and field when  i18n.locale is modified.

Component:

```
<input type="text" name="mail" v-validate="'required|email'" />
{{ errors.first("mail") }}
```

setup within index.js:

```
import ru from "vee-validate/dist/locale/ru";
import en from "vee-validate/dist/locale/en";    
import VueI18n from "vue-i18n";

Vue.use(VueI18n);

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: "ru"
});

Vue.use(VeeValidate, {
  i18n,
  dictionary: {
    ru: {
      messages: ru.messages,
      attributes: { mail: "Эл.почта" }
    },
    en: {
      messages: en.messages,
      attributes: { mail: "mail test" }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This matches how the documentation looks: https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/localization.html#vuei18n-integration

Answer (score 1):

I could get it to work, but I don't know if this is the best solution.

I'm using Laravel and a [generator package](https://github.com/martinlindhe/laravel-vue-i18n-generator) to create the translation files out of the php lang files.

JS File:

```
/**
 * For translations in Vue use i18n Package
 */
import VueInternationalization from 'vue-i18n';
import Locale from './vue-i18n-locales.generated';
Vue.use(VueInternationalization);
const i18n = new VueInternationalization({
    locale: 'de',
    messages: Locale
});


/**
 * Form Validation
 */
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';
import { ValidationProvider } from 'vee-validate';
import de from 'vee-validate/dist/locale/de';
import en from 'vee-validate/dist/locale/en';
import fr from 'vee-validate/dist/locale/fr';
Vue.use(VeeValidate, {
    i18n,
    dictionary: {
        en: {
            messages: en.messages,
            attributes: Locale.en.attributes, // I use a lang file called attributes
        },
        de: {
            messages: de.messages,
            attributes: Locale.de.attributes,
        },
        fr: {
            messages: fr.messages,
            attributes: Locale.fr.attributes,
        },
    },
});
```

For changing the locale use in JS:

```
i18n.locale = 'fr';
```

For Managing the Translation Files I recommend using [BabelEdit](https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit)

Answer (score -1):

You can make a dictionary like this

```
const dictionary = {
  en: {
    messages: {
      required: (field, val) => `Field ${field} is required`
    }
  },
  ru: {
    messages: {
      required: (field, val) => `поле ${field} обязательно`
    }
  },
};

export default dictionary;
```

You have to import it in your component and add to the validator library like this

```
this.$validator.localize(dictionary);
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Yes, but i'm using i18n, not the vee-validate's localization.