# Vue-i18n Integration by vee-validate not working as described in the documentation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate, vue-i18n

Hello I did a copy/paste from the [vee-validate documentation](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/localization.html#vuei18n-integration) into [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/pj4xpy87rj) codesandbox and I get no validation message - just the following error on the console:

```
[vue-i18n] Cannot translate the value of keypath 'validations.messages._default'. Use the value of keypath as default.
```

Is it a bug within vue-validate , vue-i18n, vuejs ? Or should one configurate it somehow different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to initialize i18n

After

```
const i18n = new VueI18n();
```

add this line

```
i18n.locale = "en";
```

this line tells i18n what the language it should look for, and merges all  your translations (that you can have in a json file) with the veevalidator translations of the given language

Comment: You are right about the line - it works! Thanks a lot!
But it is the documentation who forgot it not me :) - I did just copy and paste without knowledge of how it exactly works

Comment: @AlexanderMihailov .. o yes.. the veevalidator is really good, but it's documentation is very incomplete